# Python 3.4 and 3.5 - JsonDecodeError compatibility

Tags: python

From `python 3.4` to `3.5` the error handling in Json module has changed.

- in `3.5` decoding raises `JSONDecodeError`
- in `3.4` decoding raises `ValueError`

My actual way to write a compatible script is:

```
try:
    from json import JSONDecodeError
except ImportError:
    JSONDecodeError = ValueError
```

What is the best practice to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`JSONDecodeError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecodeError) is a subclass of `ValueError`, so you can maintain compatibility with both newer and older versions by simply sticking with `ValueError`:

```
try:
    json.load(f)
except ValueError:
    handle_decode_error()
```